# Export to excel without using the com object

Tags: c#, excel

I'm exporting a dataset to an Excel sheet, but I don't want to use the COM of Excel, because it takes a lot of time.

I need a method that exports to Excel without using the MS Office Interop, and I need to load the method using an empty Excel template so that the new Excel sheet has the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Available via Nuget and LGPL licensed. Let's you create and manage xlsx spreadsheets using OOXML.

Answer (score 2):

You could reach an excel file and update its contents using ADO.NET and the Jet OleDbProvider

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=your_path\test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;'";
using(OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    c.Open();
    string commandString = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (F1, F2, F3) values('F1Text', 'F2Text', 'F3Text')" ;
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandString))
    {
        cmd.Connection = c;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like this [xlslinq](http://xlslinq.codeplex.com/)

But you can also use this [library](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) as it will export it to a dataset

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx)

You will be able to do everything you requested and on top of that it is very fast.