# Export Sql data to Excel very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, export, export-to-excel

I am exporting Sql data to Excel. The code I am using currently is :

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // Create sql connection string
            string conString = "Data Source=DELL\\SQLSERVER1;Trusted_Connection=True;DATABASE=Zelen;CONNECTION RESET=FALSE";

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString);
            sqlCon.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select LocalSKU,ItemName, QOH,Price,Discontinued,CAST(Barcode As varchar(25)) As Barcode,Integer2,Integer3,ISNULL(SalePrice,0.0000)AS SalePrice,SaleOn,ISNULL(Price2,0.0000)AS Price2 from dbo.Inventory", sqlCon);

            System.Data.DataTable dtMainSQLData = new System.Data.DataTable();

            da.Fill(dtMainSQLData);
            DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns;

            // Export Data into EXCEL Sheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);



            int i = 1;
            int j = 1;
            int s = 1;
            //header row
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtMainSQLData.Columns)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = col.ColumnName;
                j++;

                ExcelApp.Rows.AutoFit();
                ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
            }

            i++;

            //data rows
            foreach (DataRow row in dtMainSQLData.Rows)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count + 1; k++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[i, k] = "'" + row[k - 1].ToString();
                }

                i++;
                s++;
                Console.Write(s);
                Console.Write("\n\r");

                ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                ExcelApp.Rows.AutoFit();
            }

            var b = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Sheet1.xlsx";
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(b);

            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();

            Console.WriteLine(".xlsx file Exported succssessfully.");
```

Takes are 70000 rows in my sql database. I am running this script in Console application.
It takes more then an hour to export it to excel file.

How can I use this to export it faster?

Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: That is the nature of the excel coms. I don't believe you can speed it up.

Comment: An alternative is using OleDb treating Excel sheets like datatables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312661/performance-of-oledb-to-read-excel/11352167#11352167 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208255/export-to-excel-without-using-the-com-object/11208362#11208362

Comment: I would suggest exporting as a CSV instead of an excel.  It should be lightning fast and is still easily supported by excel.

Comment: There was a similar question recently (reading values) -- it was said that it had to do with the cell-by-cell operation... If you could do a range instead, it may speed it up.

Comment: @bdimag comments triggered a memory, doing a row at a time instead of cell by cell is indeed faster.  Also, there is no reason to autofit your columns on every cell.  Get rid of those calls and do it once at the very end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option 1:

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214534/1967692). Use a library called ClosedXML to write the data to Excel.

Option 2:

Get a range big enough for all of the data and set the value equal to a 2 dimensional range. This works very fast without another referencing another library. I tried with 70000 records.

```
// Get an excel instance
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

// Get a workbook
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();

// Get a worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();
ws.Name = "Test Export";

// Add column names to the first row
int col = 1;
foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns) {
    ws.Cells[1, col] = c.ColumnName;
    col++;
}

// Create a 2D array with the data from the table
int i = 0;
string[,] data = new string[table.Rows.Count, table.Columns.Count];
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {                
    int j = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns) {
        data[i,j] = row[c].ToString();
        j++;
    }
    i++;            
}                   

// Set the range value to the 2D array
ws.Range[ws.Cells[2, 1], ws.Cells[table.Rows.Count + 1, table.Columns.Count]].value = data;

// Auto fit columns and rows, show excel, save.. etc
excel.Columns.AutoFit();
excel.Rows.AutoFit();
excel.Visible = true;
```

Edit: This version exported a million records on my machine it takes about a minute. This example uses Excel interop and breaks the rows in to chunks of 100,000.

```
// Start a stopwatch to time the process
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Check if there are rows to process
if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0) {

    // Determine the number of chunks
    int chunkSize = 100000;
    double chunkCountD = (double)table.Rows.Count / (double)chunkSize;
    int chunkCount = table.Rows.Count / chunkSize;
    chunkCount = chunkCountD > chunkCount ? chunkCount + 1 : chunkCount;

    // Instantiate excel
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    // Get a workbook
    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();

    // Get a worksheet
    Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();
    ws.Name = "Test Export";

    // Add column names to excel
    int col = 1;                
    foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns) {
        ws.Cells[1, col] = c.ColumnName;
        col++;
    }

    // Build 2D array
    int i = 0;
    string[,] data = new string[table.Rows.Count, table.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
        int j = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns) {
            data[i, j] = row[c].ToString();
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    int processed = 0;
    int data2DLength = data.GetLength(1);
    for (int chunk = 1; chunk <= chunkCount; chunk++) {
        if (table.Rows.Count - processed < chunkSize) chunkSize = table.Rows.Count - processed;            
        string[,] chunkData = new string[chunkSize, data2DLength];
        int l = 0;
        for (int k = processed; k < chunkSize + processed; k++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < data2DLength; m++) {
                chunkData[l,m] = table.Rows[k][m].ToString();
            }
            l++;
        }
        // Set the range value to the chunk 2d array
        ws.Range[ws.Cells[2 + processed, 1], ws.Cells[processed + chunkSize + 1, data2DLength]].value = chunkData;
        processed += chunkSize;
    }

    // Auto fit columns and rows, show excel, save.. etc
    excel.Columns.AutoFit();
    excel.Rows.AutoFit();
    excel.Visible = true;                
}

// Stop the stopwatch and display the seconds elapsed
sw.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

Comment: I know this is late but i tried implementing your Option 2 to my problem (which is very similar to OP's problem) and I am unable to cast a worksheet. I was wondering does this solution support .net framework 2.0 as my app is an old app?

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data to as CSV formant you can load that into Excel, Here is some code i have modified from The Code Project site here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665519/Writing-a-DataTable-to-a-CSV-file

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
        // Create Connection object
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"<Your Connection String>"))
        {
            // Create Command object
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM <Your Table>", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\dump.csv"))
                        {
                            DataConvert.ToCSV(dt, writer, false);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Stop timing
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write result
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
            stopwatch.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public static class DataConvert
{
    public static void ToCSV(DataTable sourceTable, TextWriter writer, bool includeHeaders)
    {
        if (includeHeaders)
        {
            List<string> headerValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in sourceTable.Columns)
            {
                headerValues.Add(QuoteValue(column.ColumnName));
            }

            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headerValues.ToArray()));
        }

        string[] items = null;
        foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
        {
            items = row.ItemArray.Select(o => QuoteValue(o.ToString())).ToArray();
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", items));
        }

        writer.Flush();
    }

    private static string QuoteValue(string value)
    {
        return String.Concat("\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"");
    }
}
```

}

On my PC this took 30 seconds to process 1 million records...

Comment: @jiverson Code is pretty efficient, processed 1 million records (3 columns) in under 60 seconds. Just a note to the OP, you can still save the data as a xlsx file by calling the SaveAs() function of Worksheet object [ws.SaveAs("Sheet1.xlsx");]

Comment: And i have just found this on Code Project site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML. it uses OpenXML instead of Interop so will run on a system that does not have MS Office installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function:

After set your data in a datatable.

```
Public Shared Sub ExportDataSetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.Charset = ""
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
                response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Microsoft Open XML SDK's Open XML Writer.  Open XML is the format all the new office files are in.

[Export a large data query (60k+ rows) to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370672/export-a-large-data-query-60k-rows-to-excel/42304339#42304339)

Vincent Tan has a nice article on the topic.

http://polymathprogrammer.com/2012/08/06/how-to-properly-use-openxmlwriter-to-write-large-excel-files/